# PipeLine with multiple Transformations

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to understand the lifecycle of transforms within a pipeline.

I have a pipleline with several transforms.

```
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
p.apply(TextIO.Read.named("ReadLines").from(inputFile))
            .apply(new ReadData())
            .apply(new Match())
            .apply(new Record())
            .apply(BigQueryIO.Write
                    .to(tableRef)
                    .withSchema(getSchema())
                    .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
                    .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE));
```

Inside each of these transformations is a single DoFn.  Does the entire batch that the node is processing need to be complete before moving to the next transformation?

What I am observing at least with the DirectPipelineRunner is that the entire dataset is read before the match transformation is run.

Answer (score 2):

With DirectPipelineRunner, the transforms are executed entirely serially as you observed.  When running with the DataflowPipelineRunner without --streaming set, many transforms can be fused together and will all run simultaneously.  With --streaming, data will continually stream through the entire pipeline, and all transforms will be active.

Comment: Can you clarify simultaneously when using the DataflowPIpelineRunner?

Comment: If two transforms are fused, the second will process each output element of the first as soon as the first one produces it.